# Relation between depth-only FBO and fragment shader

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader, fbo, depth-buffer

I’ve been wondering what happens when binding a depth-only FBO (only the `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` gets attached and `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)` is called) for the fragment shader part. Because any color is discarded:

- does OpenGL simply process vertices the regular way, call the rasterizer, apply the fragment shader for rasterized fragments, but discard any result
- or does it do smarter things, like process vertices until the optional geometry shader, then cut the fragment shader part and use a dummy fragment shader in order to discard useless color computations?

Because of *vendor-implementation* details, I guess it might vary, but I’d like to have a better idea about that topic.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the fragment shader will still run even if it has no outputs. This can be used for example to draw shadow maps with punch-through alpha textures, using discard.

If it does have outputs (or more outputs then are bound), then they should just be ignored. I'd imagine that a smart driver could easily skip the fragment shader entirely if it doesn't contain any discard statements.

Also perhaps look into Separate Shader Objects (https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/separate_shader_objects.txt). It allows you to disable the stages manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've read (Though never personally tested) that a complete lack of a color buffer causes strange undefined behavior, as OpenGL implementations each had to ask this question in reverse: "What /should/ we make it do when there's no color buffer?" and have no official, commonly-used-across-all-implementations answer.

The official documentation carefully avoids mentioning this situation generally.

As such, it is just recommended that you simply... not do that, and instead always have a color buffer, even if you don't use it.